# JDK 11 Install Issue

Tags: java

So i was trying to start Java, and download JDK 11. Also updated the JRE to the latest version. After installation and compiling my first "hello world" to "*xxx.class*", trying to run it with:

```
java xxx
```

turned up an error of incompatible versions (the compiled file was v.55 while the JRE version only interpreted files up to version 52.)

So i unistalled JDK 11 and installed JDK 8. Now in my Java folder there is both a JDK.version_xxx and a JRE.version_xxx file, whereas when i installed JDK 11 there wasn't a JRE file installed (which i think was stated in the changes that happened in the new JDK 11 version).

Where and what JRE do i need to get to run files compiled with JDK 11?

Comment: Please try to set the class path using `path` variable in environment variable.

Comment: You don't set the classpath using the "path" variable.  And setting the classpath is not the problem here anyway!

Comment: A JDK includes a JRE. There is no need to install a separate one. If you installed Java 11, you can use that JDK to compile and run Java files. Apparently the command `java` picked up a different Java installation. Adjust your `PATH` variable to only include the Java 11 `bin` directory or at least make it appear **before** the Java 8 JRE.  _How_ you do that depends on the operating system you are using. Or call the binaries explicitly, e.g. `\path\to\java11\bin\javac Hello.java` and then `\path\to\java11\bin\java.exe Hello` instead of relying on the PATH

Comment: Thanks anonymous horse! I unistalled JRE 8 and now it works. But now i got even more confused. If the JDK does contain a JRE, why do they say in the official docs that JRE is not included?

Comment: @Akenaten They didn't. They only say that they don't release a standalone JRE. But the `java` command will still be available in the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

JRE is no longer part of Java 11, as per 
[JDK 11 Release Notes](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html):

> In this release, the JRE or Server JRE is no longer offered. Only the JDK is offered. Users can use jlink to create smaller custom runtimes.

Either compile against version of the target JRE or build a custom runtime with `jlink`.

Comment: I literally just started learning Java yesterday, i have the typical "hello world" program that i want to run. How am i supposed to learn the language if i have to "build my own custom runtime images with selected modules"  on my first day when i don't even know what that means. Jesus christ.

Comment: @Akenaten find a tutorial for Java 11 or downgrade to an older version, Java 8 being the most popular. The platform is moving forward.